# Infinite looping

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

my program get infinite looping and I need the best solution.

the function I have is really linked to each others, so it might complicated to see.

where dt = 0.04, dx = 1 , a = 0.7, b = 0.4

the matters is to search p(x,t+1) need p(x,t), p(x-1,t) and p(x+1,t)
it also happen to other function.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double a,b,dt,dx; 

    public void JudulKolom() //to print in table, cause I planned to make p,q,n graphic using zedGraph 
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("t").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("x").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("p(x,t)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("q(x,t)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("n(x,t)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("r(x,t)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("c(x,t)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("f(c)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("g(c)").Width =100;
        listView1.Columns.Add("h(c)").Width =100;
    }

    //fungsi p(x,t)          
    double fP (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        a = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxAlfa.Text); 
        if (t == 0) //for every t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = 0.01 * Math.Exp(-0.1 * x);
        }
        else //for t=0.04 or t+1
        {             
            if (x > 0) //for p when x=1..10 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fP(x,t-dt) + fD() * (fP(x+1,t-dt) - 2 * fP(x,t-dt) + fP(x-1,t-dt)) + 
                        dt * fG(x,t-dt) * (1 - fR(x,t-dt)) - fF(x,t-dt) * fP(x,t-dt) + fP(x,t-dt) * Math.Sqrt(dt) * wiener(x);        
            }
            else if (x == 0) //only for p when x=0 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fP(x,t-dt) + fD() * (fP(x+1,t-dt) - 2 * fP(x,t-dt) + fP(x,t-dt)) + 
                        dt * fG(x,t-dt) * (1 - fR(x,t-dt)) - fF(x,t-dt) * fP(x,t-dt) + fP(x,t-dt) * Math.Sqrt(dt) * wiener(x); 
            }
        }

        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi q(x,t)
    double fQ (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        if (t == 0) //for every q when t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > 0)  //for q when x=1..10 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fQ(x,t-dt) + fD() * (fQ(x+1,t-dt) - 2*fQ(x,t-dt) + fQ(x-1,t-dt)) +
                        dt * fF(x,t-dt) * fP(x,t-dt) - 
                        (0.5 * fF(x,t-dt)) * fQ(x,t-dt); 
            }
            else if (x == 0) //only for q when x=0 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fQ(x,t-dt) + fD() * (fQ(x+1,t-dt) - 2*fQ(x,t-dt) + fQ(x,t-dt)) +
                        dt * fF(x,t-dt) * fP(x,t-dt) - 
                        (0.5 * fF(x,t-dt)) * fQ(x,t-dt);
            }
        }
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi n(x,t)
    double fN (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil=0;
        if (t == 0) //for every n when t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > 0)  //only for n when x=1..10 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fN(x,t-dt) + dt * (0.5 * fF(x,t-dt)) * fQ(x,t-dt); 
            }
            else if (x == 0) //only for n when x=0 and t=0.04
            {
                hasil = fN(x,t-dt) + dt * (0.5 * fF(x,t-dt)) * fQ(x,t-dt); 
            }                
        }
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi r(x,t)
    double fR (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;

        hasil = fP(x,t) + fQ(x,t) + fN(x,t); //for every any x and t

        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi c(x,t)
    double fC (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        a = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxAlfa.Text);
        if (t == 0) //for every C when t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = ((1.0 * 10) / (10 + fP(x,t)))*(1.0 - a * fR(x,t)); //the matter is the R function that I have to use fR value in fC(c,t=0)  when I look for fC(x,t=0.04)
        }
        else if (t != 0) //for every C when t is not 0 and any x
        { 
            hasil = ((1.0 * 10) / (10 + fP(x,t-dt)))*(1.0 - a * fR(x,t-dt));
        }
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi f(c)
    double fF (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        if (t == 0) //for every F when t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = 0.5 * (1-Math.Tanh(4 * fC(x,t) - 2));
        }
        else if (t != 0) //for every F when t is not 0 and any x
        {
            hasil = 0.5 * (1-Math.Tanh(4 * fC(x,t-dt) - 2));
        }        
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi g(c)
    double fG (int x, double t)
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        b = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxBeta.Text);
        if (t == 0) //for every G when t=0 and any x
        {
            hasil = b * Math.Exp(b * fC(x,t));
        }
        else if (t != 0) //for every G when t is not 0 and any x
        {
            hasil = b * Math.Exp(b * fC(x,t-dt));
        }
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    //fungsi h(c)
    double fH (double f) //only for q when x=0 and t=0.04
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        hasil = 0.5 * f;
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    double fD ()
    {
        double hasil = 0;
        hasil = 1.0 * dt / (dx * dx);
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    double wiener (int x)
    {
        double hasil = 0, dt = 0.04, Pi = 3.14159265358979;    
        hasil = 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2 * Pi * dt) * Math.Exp(-1.0 * Math.Pow(x,2) / (2 * dt));
        return Math.Round(hasil, 6);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (textBoxAlfa.Text == "" || textBoxBeta.Text == "" || tbXvalue.Text == "" || tbTvalue.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Semua input harus diisi angka!");
        }
        else
        {
            double p=0,q=0,n=0;
            double r,a,c,f,g,h,t;
            int x;

            a = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxAlfa.Text);         
            b = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxBeta.Text);               
            t = Convert.ToDouble(tbTvalue.Text);
            x = Convert.ToInt32(tbXvalue.Text);

            dt=0.04;
            dx=1;

            int indeks=-1;
         while (t<=0.08) 
         {
            x = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) 
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(t.ToString());
                indeks=indeks+1;

                        p=fP(x,t);
                        q=fQ(x,t);
                        n=fN(x,t);
                        r=fR(x,t);
                        c=fC(x,t);
                        f=fF(x,t);
                        g=fG(x,t);
                        h=fH(f);

                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(x.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(p.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(q.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(n.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(r.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(c.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(f.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(g.ToString());
                listView1.Items[indeks].SubItems.Add(h.ToString());
            }
            t=t+0.04;                
            JudulKolom();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is looping infinitely? Have you tried setting breakpoints?

Comment: Your code is very messy. Consider cleaning it up and provide some comments where things might get complicated. As it is now, your only `while` loop should not be infinite since you increase `t`.

Comment: I see no possible infinite loops in your code. But it can be possible endless recursion in your methods calculating f*-functions. Use debugger to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Your function `fN` calls `fN` and that will most probably get stuck unless `t` ever is exactly 0 on an iteration. Set breakpoints and step through your code, if still stuck, create a short example that displays the problem

Comment: @Sayse `fN` will also exit if **x** is ever less than 0. The methods `fQ` and `fP` have the exact same issue as well.

Comment: @EBrown - Yes, but `x` never changes

Comment: @EBrown you all also find this interesting right? some of my friends who work as programmer also find it interesting. 
however, x didn't change but because I use forward difference  and backward difference approximation, I still need the value of x in previous.

if you are interested to help me more, I can give you an excel version.

Comment: @Timoth The underlying problem, is that as we have said, `fN`, `fQ`, and `fP` call each other. The provided answer should also shed light: when working with `double` values, the actual value is almost never actually 0, you should definitely create an acceptable `delta` around 0 that you can tolerate. (I.e. `0.0001` or something - whatever your largest error tolerance is.)

Answer (score 1):

you should not compare floating point numbers by equating.  You need to allow some imprecision. something like `if (Math.Abs(a - b) < epsilon) {}` Change your checking `if (t == 0)` to `if (Math.Abs(t) < 0.00001)` or some allowed small number.

I think, `dt` in your formulas is defined for this.

Comment: Try to locate which part of code is causing loop. Remove calculations and return constant value from most inner function (which not calling other functions). Give readable names to variables.